# ¿Como utilizar un comparador para ordenar una lista dentro de una clase?

Tags: c++, comparaciones

```
class Coloreo {
    vector<int> assigned_color;

    bool compare (int a, int b) {
        return assigned_color[a] < assigned_color[b];
    }

public:

    vector<int> coloreo_secuencial (Grafo & g) {
        int n = g.size();
        assigned_color.resize(n, -1);
        assigned_color[0] = 0;
        for (int u = 1; u < n; u++) {
            int c = 0;
            list<int> edges = g.getVerticesAdyacentes(u);
            edges.sort(compare);
            for (int v : edges) {
                if (assigned_color[v] == c) {
                    c++;
                }
            }
            assigned_color[u] = c;
        }
        return assigned_color;
    }
};
```

Quiero usar el comparador `compare` para ordenar la lista `edges`: `edges.sort(compare);` pero me lanza el siguiente error:
`error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* __comp) (...)'|`

Lo curioso es que si lo hago todo afuera de la clase, si me deja hacerlo. Con esto me refiero a que `vector<int> assigned_color;` lo coloco como global y las demas funciones en el main y anda todo bien, pero cuando lo quiero meter en una clase no me deja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu caso `compare` es una función miembro de `Coloreo`, es decir, para que esa llamada funcionase habría que escribir algo similar a:

```
edges.sort(compare(this));
```

Pero claro, esto no va a compilar en la vida.

**Opción 1**

Una posible alternativa es convertir la función en estática. El problema que te encuentras aquí es que la función `compare` hace uso de `assigned_color`, que es una variable miembro de `Coloreo`... esta variable también debería ser estática:

```
class Coloreo {
    static vector<int> assigned_color;

    static bool compare (int a, int b) {
```

De esta forma ya sí debería funcionarte, puesto que ahora `compare`, como toda función estática, no precisará de una instancia de `Coloreo`.

Ahora bien, dependiendo del resto del código que no has puesto en la pregunta es posible que esta opción no sea aplicable a tu caso... en ese caso necesitamos un adaptador para poder llamar a `this->compare` dentro de la función `sort`. Si C++11 es una opción podemos usar una función lambda:

```
edges.sort([this](int a, int b){ return this->compare(a,b); });
```

Lo que hace esta lambda es quedarse con el `this`, puntero que apunta a la instancia de `Coloreo` y usarlo para poder llamar a la función miembro `compare`.

**Opción 2**

Si las lambdas no son una opción te queda la opción de usar una clase:

```
struct Coloreo {
    struct Adaptador
    {
      Coloreo & instancia;

      Adaptador(Coloreo & instancia)
        : instancia(instancia)
      { }

      bool operator()(int a, int b)
      { return instancia.compare(a, b); }
    };

// ...
edges.sort(Adaptador(*this));
```

En este caso el adaptador implementa el operador función. Su lógica es equivalente al de la lambda.

Comment: `Adaptador(Coloreo & instancia) : instancia(instancia) { }` no entiendo esta sentencia.

Comment: @GuidoModarelli Es el constructor del adaptador. Los dos puntos sirven para inicializar los miembros de la clase. En este caso hacemos que la variable miembro, que es una referencia, apunte al objeto que se le pasa como argumento

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el argumento y la variable miembro se llaman igual... si la inicializacion no se hiciese en los dos puntos habría que usar `this` para eliminar la ambigüedad. Eso sí,  las referencias no se pueden inicializar de otra forma